# Dot operator in javascript

Tags: javascript

I think that the dot operator can be apply to object only for access to his properties. I.e. for instance

```
var o={prop:'property'};
alert(o.prop);//property
```

When JS executing `alert(o.prop);` first object which contains by reference `o` will found further will be found property wich contains by reference `o.prop`.

Let's write

```
simple='hello';
alert(simple.length);//5
```

I dont understand this. I'm excepted that in console will kind of error, because simple is no object.

Comment: Sure it is, `simple` is a `string` object. Everything in JavaScript is an object

Comment: @Adam I think you are not correct, number, string, boolean undefined, null are not object. Can you delete your comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm excepted that in console will kind of error, because `simple` is no object.

Actually, it *is* a `String` object. JS [implicitly converts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects) the primitive string type to a `String` object when you apply string methods to it.

It's wrong to say that "everything is an object" in JavaScript because there *are* primitive types that are not objects, including a string primitive. In many cases the implicit conversion between primitives and objects can easily obscure the fact.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

> JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so
>   that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.

Comment: In ECMA-262 reffered to `[[Extensible]]` internal property. Is it true that for all primitives converted to object JS automatically set `[[Extensible]]=false;`?

Answer (score 4):

What's happening when you do something like `simple.length` is that, under-the-hood, the browser is *temporarily* converting `simple` into an object of type `String` and then looking up `length` on that. It's almost like calling `new String(simple)` except the browser doesn't actually need to create a new object, it just needs to behave as if it did. One thing to note is that this is all temporary:

```
simple.newProp = 123;   // will execute fine
simple.newProp;         // will return undefined
```

Comment: @SurajJain I can't remember exactly - it was a long time ago. Maybe it was 'Professional JavaScript for Web Developers' by Nicholas Zakas (his blog posts are great too). It's also probably in the language spec if you're feeling masochistic.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.

So your `simple` var is a string instance, and it's inherits from `String.prototype`.

Ref:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, <strike>everything is an object</strike>.

- {} === object
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) === object (an array, but still, an object, as it has properties which are normally not shown to you like `length` and `indexOf()`, etc)
- [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) === object again! (that's where you get the string.length property from)

Checkout this [list of objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects) JS has. Just because you can't see

## { }

does not mean that the variable is not an object. To get a list of properties of a data-type, you can write this in your console:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(String)
```

And depending on what [your browser supports](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/), you'll get this:

```
[
 "prototype", "quote", "substring", "toLowerCase", "toUpperCase",
 "charAt", "charCodeAt", "contains", "indexOf", "lastIndexOf", 
 "startsWith", "endsWith", "trim", "trimLeft", "trimRight",
 "toLocaleLowerCase", "toLocaleUpperCase", "localeCompare",
 "match", "search", "replace", "split", "substr", "concat",
 "slice", "fromCharCode", "length", "name", "arguments", "caller"
]
```

Comment: Do you mean that when we write simple='hello' we have an object with `[[Extensible]]=false;` internal property

Comment: Your example disproves your point: try `Object.getOwnPropertyNames( "hello" )`.

Comment: @Juhana: the "hello" here is not a String object, it's a string [primitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Distinction_between_string_primitives_and_String_objects). It's the same for Numbers and Booleans.

You'll have to try this: `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new String("hello"));` which will return `[length, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was saying. The OP does *not* have `new String("hello")`, they have just `"hello"`. "In JavaScript, everything is an object" -- except things that are not objects, right?

Answer (score 1):

String is an object inherent to JS. As such, it also has inherent properties, length being one of them. This property spits out the number of characters that are in a String object(as you've seen.)

If you wanted to you could override the inherent abilities of any inherent JS Object (String, Array, etc.) and create your own functionality, but that is generally a really bad idea.