# Why does ({"word"}) return its length?

Tags: javascript, string-length

I'm puzzled by this solution to finding the length of a string:

`const getLength = ({length}) => length`

I'm familiar with object and array destructuring, but couldn't find anything about string destructuring(?) or how this would return the length. The concept of adding curly braces to the function parameter is also alien to me.

Comment: 1) An instance of `String` is also an `Object` (by extension). 2) A `String` instance has a `length` property. 3) What you're looking at there is argument destructuring

Comment: This is also worth a read ~ [Dot operator in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20658222/283366)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making a function that requests that an object parameter be destructured into just its "length" property. When you pass a string, the string will be coerced to a String instance so you get the "length" property value, which the function returns.

See what happens when you try this:

```
console.log(getLength({ length: "Hello world" }));
```

Comment: Another way to read this is `const getLength = (obj) => { return obj.length }` `{}` is destructing as @Pointy pointed out.

Comment: Note in console.log(getLength({ length: "Hello world" })); you're not destructuring, just passing an object as the argument for getLength. Then getLength destructures the length property out of that object. Probably obvious but it confused me for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

> `const getLength =`

Starts the assignment for the getLength constant, then the

> `({length})`

[destructuring assignment <sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) takes the input argument and unpacks the length property value, and finally

> `=> length`

the arrow function returns the referenced length value.

---

```js
const getLength = ({length}) => length;

document.querySelector("#b").onclick = function(){
 document.querySelector("#d").innerText = getLength(document.querySelector("#i").value);
};
```

```html
<input id="i" /><input type="button" id="b" value="Try Me" /><br>
<div id="d"></div>
```

Comment: It's a destructuring parameter declaration. No assignment to be seen :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Going to disagree. "destructuring parameter declaration" is just community jargon. There is syntactic sugar that allows the process to be hidden, but behind the scenes the parameter is the target of a destructuring assignment. In fact, all destructuring involves assignment. In other words, the syntax behind the scenes is `let {length} = "hello"` for the arrow function's parameter, whereby we are left with 5 for length. As well, I don't see any defined syntax using the phrase destructuring parameter in the ecma specs. Perhaps you could provide a citation for your claim.

Comment: Formally, it's a *BindingInitialization* of a *BindingPattern*. I'd like to distinguish those variable initialisations (also found in variable declarations like `let`) from assignment expressions - they use separate (if similar) algorithms in the spec as well. But of course we need better jargon than that (nobody uses the term "binding"). The spec prose distinguishes between "destructuring assignments" and the more generic "destructuring patterns". So to be precise: it's a formal parameter destructuring pattern, not a destructuring assignment.